# Regression: Generalized Additive Model

Tags: r, regression, transformation, mgcv

I have started to work with GAM in R and I’ve acquired Simon Wood’s excellent book on the topic. Based on one of his examples, I am looking at the following:

```
library(mgcv)
data(trees)
ct1<-gam(log(Volume) ~ Height + s(Girth), data=trees)
```

I have two general questions to this example:

1. How does one decide when a variable in the model estimation should be parametric (such as Height) or when it should be smooth (such as Girth)? Does one hold an advantage over the other and is there a way to determine what is the optimal type for a variable is? If anybody has any literature about this topic, I’d be happy to know of it.
2. Say I want to look closer at the weights of `ct1`: `ct1$coefficients`. Can I use them as the `gam`-procedure outputs them, or do I have to transform them before analyzing them given that I am fitting to `log(Volume)`? In the case of the latter, I guess I would have to use `exp (ct1$coefficients)`

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a question about programming. If you have questions about statistical models, you should ask over at [stats.se].

Comment: Agree is more a methods request than an actual programming question, i.e it's really about how to think about and execute back-transformation. That said, sometimes the CV.com people will close questions if they are restricted to one language. So my advice would be to edit the question with the output of summary(ct1) as well as making a good faith effort to read ?predict.gam and use it on your gam-object. You might also look at: `cor( predict(ct1), predict( lm( log(Volume) ~ Height + I(Girth^2/(2*pi)), data=trees) ) )`. Then there will be something more general for the CV-readers to chew on.

Comment: Incidentally the best linear model for `log(Volume)` I found was `~ Height + I(Girth^(3/2))`. You might ponder why I chose that exponent, and furthr ponder why it's always good to ask the question: "What is the science?" or "what is the geometry?" behind the model you are making.